# Xarray - Changing Data Variables into Dimensions

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am working with a lot of temperature data which has been measured at different longitudes and latitudes and I can open it from a NetCDF file like this.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (altitude: 801, measurement_number: 3180)
Coordinates:
   * altitude           (altitude) float64 0.0 100.0 200.0 300.0 400.0 500.0 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: measurement_number
Data variables:
    temperature        (measurement_number, altitude) float32 ...
    longitude          (measurement_number) float64 ...
    latitude           (measurement_number) float64 ...
```

To evaluate the results more conveniently I want to change the variables "longitude" and "latitude" into dimensions or coordinates like this.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:            (altitude: 801, measurement_number: 3180, longitude: 36, latitude: 18)
Coordinates:
   * altitude           (altitude) float64 0.0 100.0 200.0 300.0 400.0 500.0 ...
   * longitude          (longitude) float64 -180, -170, -160 ...
   * latitude           (latitude) float64 -90, -80, -70, ...
Dimensions without coordinates: measurement_number
Data variables:
    temperature        (measurement_number, altitude, longitude, latitude) float32 ...
```

I tried to get to here by using `ds.set_coords(['longitude','latitude'])`, and lots of different functions, but I cannot make the temperature depending on longitude and latitude. Can you give me a tip how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [Multi-index](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html?highlight=multiindex#multiindex-coordinates) feature in xarray? It may not be exactly what you are looking for and there are some limitations (e.g. serialisation to netCDF is not yet supported as far as i know), but maybe that is okay for you. The idea is to turn measurement_number into a pandas multiindex with latitude and longitude as virtual coordinates.
You can then use .sel on multiindex coordinates aswell -> [Multi-level indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#multi-level-indexing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The approach is working out really nice. I introduced the Multi-Index and then unstacked it
    `ds = ds.set_index(n_event=['longitude','latitude'])`
    `ds = ds.unstack('n_event')`

I had to unstack it, because I wanted to take the mean value over all longitudes and save the file back to an netCDF file
    `ds = ds.mean(dim='n_event')`
    `ds.to_netcdf('combinedlatlon.nc')`

but I always get a memory error before the file can be saved. I guess now I have to look a bit more into dask and chunking.